# mysql IS NULL/LIKE %% condition

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a query that's giving me a hard time.

Basically, I have a column in my database `race` that holds a dynamic value (these examples aren't the real deal content wise, but the code is the same).

race can be NULL (no specific race required)
or race can hold 1 or more values ("human,lizard,dog" etc)

My query is:

`$var = $db->Query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE race LIKE "%'.$specie.'%" OR race IS NULL');`

However, this is not working. Is there an error in the flow of this statement that will make the query return nothing? (The default 'empty result' is displayed)

EDIT: In english I want my query to say "Select all data if a specific race is found, or if there is no race requirement at all (null)"

Comment: Have you checked if SELECT * FROM table WHERE race LIKE "%'.$specie.'%" works (without the OR part)?

Comment: Yes, under the right conditions without the OR it works, however that alone will break the system because it does not select anything else, which is bad and my need for the IS NULL part

Comment: $var = $db->Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE race LIKE '%".$specie."%' OR race = ''");

Comment: Ali, why would that work? = "" is not the same as IS NULL according to google. It says you can't apply = > < or <> to a NULL value

Comment: Please post the query string after concatenation. There must be something weird taking place, that can only be detected when seeing the final query that is to be executed, I suspect.

Comment: @RandomSeed in the actual script it's stored in an array and joined into the query by AND statements (I did not write that part, another coder did and it's worked perfectly until I tried to add this statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are interested in [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), given your possible values are stored comma separated:

```
$var = $db->Query('SELECT * 
                   FROM table 
                   WHERE 
                       FIND_IN_SET("' . $specie . '", race)
                       OR race IS NULL
                  ');
```

Standard remarks apply here:

- Don't trust user input. Always use [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) to handle input variables. [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection) is bad!
- Optimize your database to gain performance and formulate queries more precisely! race can be in an own table, use a `N:M` relationship in between.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try swapping the quotes around:

```
$var = $db->Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE race LIKE '%".$specie."%' OR race IS NULL");
```

At least, this is something that I would test, although I now understand that this shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Negative ghost rider, that didn't work. Switching the quotes doesn't make it different since I'm escaping the query to get the value, so there's no need for literal/parsed variable

Comment: @PRPGFerret Ah, well, soz ;) (Never heard the expression "Negative ghost rider" before..) Your table isn't called **table** is it??!

Comment: Of course not lol I'm just protecting specific values from public eye

Comment: Single- or double- quotes are strictly equivalent as far as [MySQL string litterals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html) are concerned (except in `ANSI_SQL` mode, where it would raise a syntax error). Notice only single-quotes are valid in ANSI SQL.

Comment: @RandomSeed Thank you. I suspected this might be the case, but should have checked. As I don't often see the quotes this way round (particularly around the "%") then this is something I would have tried. Andy.

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work. I sense your problem is elsewhere, like, are you using the correct schema? Is there actually something in this table?

Answer (score 0):

You could normalize your design and introduce a separate `specie_sets` and `specie_set_values`:

```
specie_sets:
    set_id (PK)

specie_set_values:
    set_id (FK) | value (INDEX)
```

Your `table` will contain a nullable reference to `specie_sets` (FK).

Then use a union:

```
(SELECT table.* 
    FROM specie_set_values 
    JOIN table ON specie_set_id = set_id
    WHERE value = :specie)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE specie_set_id IS NULL)
```